# Passing parameter to ssrs report in query-string in SharePoint 2010

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, query-string

I published an ssrs to sharepoint and am trying to pass the value of parameter in the query string but I haven't been able to figure out the syntax.  Here is the query-string that I'm passing in.  I am trying to pass the `CLordID = 1324381`.  In my report `CLordID`

> https:///_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/TestReports/Orders.rdl&rs:Command=Render&CLordID=1324381

When I try this I receive:

> Specify Parameter Values  Report
>   parameter values must be specified
>   before the report can be displayed.
>   Choose parameter values in the
>   parameters area and click the Apply
>   button.

I have tried making the parameter, visible, hidden, and internal, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This also applies to the following error Message "The report is missing a parameter value but prompting for it has been disabled. "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SSRS 2008 with Sharepoint, you need to prefix each parameter passed in the URL with "rp:". 
For example: 
https:///_layouts/ReportServer/RSViewerPage.aspx?rv:RelativeReportUrl=/TestReports/Orders.rdl&rs:Command=Render&rp:CLordID=1324381

Comment: Wow Thank You! You just saved me 20 hours of Google!

Answer (score 0):

In the parameter options, under available values, have you set the option of specify and then not included any values? Set it back to none and you should be right.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option, which is to render the reports using the HTML Viewer.

I got this idea here: http://techpunch.wordpress.com/2008/09/17/sql-server-reporting-services-url-parameters-in-sharepoint-integrated-mode/ 
I'm never sure how long a blog post will last, so I tried to summarize it below.

You could format your URL like this:
(I wasn't sure of your server name so I just used "Intranet" where applicable)

```
https://intranet/reportserver?http://intranet/TestReports/Orders.rdl&CLordID=1324381
```

This avoids having to add "rp:" to every parameter you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Include "rp:" before each parameter.
Works like a charm.